# Python Pandas column regex extract substring to end of line (\n or \r) in multil-line string

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a column that's multiline text. I want to match a specific substring and extract it along with everything up until new line. The challenge I'm facing is that there are both "\n" and "\r" and I haven't discovered how to remove the "\r" from my result. Here's the test:

```
    \r
empty
\n
\r\n
basic text
\r
WHATIWANT: - this is cool ! = . a1^@#%\r\n
more lines\r\r\r
\n
\r
\n
```

And the result I want is:

```
WHATIWANT: - this is cool ! = . a1^@#%
```

I tried using:

```
(WHATIWANT:\s.+(.*?)\s+)
```

But get this (can't get rid of the \n and \r):

```
WHATIWANT: - this is cool ! = . a1^@#%\n\r
```

Comment: How do we know how to target the single line which you seem to want here?

Comment: I want to get the substring to end of line on the line that starts with "WHATIWANT:"

Comment: This is because of greedy `.+` that renders `(.*?)` useless. Is the text above a single cell contents? If it is, and there are a mix of line endings in it, I do not see how the `re.M` helps you as `^` only matches after a newline (LF) char. Could you please update with a real string literal you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str.extract` in multiline mode should work here:

```py
df["value"] = df["col"].str.extract(r'^(WHATIWANT:.*?)\s*$', flags=re.M)
```

Comment: Close, but when I run it I still get the "\r" at the end of the string returned in the result.

Comment: I know I could do str.split("\r")[0] as a subsequent step but I can't rely on the "\r" always being present so need a way to handle "\n" and "\r".

Comment: Check the updated answer, which should fix that.  BTW...your question has a typo, your target line currently ends in `\n\r` when apparently it should be `\r\n`.

Comment: Thanks @tTim I edited the typo. I still get a result that has "\r" included at the end.

Comment: The pattern `^(WHATIWANT:.*?)\s*$` seems to be working in [this Python demo](https://rextester.com/CYGA58922).

Comment: `:-?` <-- my expression at seeing all your comments.

Comment: Outside the scope of this question, but if my starting matching substring is "WHATIWANT:" and we return the same results as you gave which includes "WHATIWANT:" in the full return string, is there a quick way to not return the "WHATIWANT:" portion?

Comment: Yes, use: `^WHATIWANT:(.*?)\s*$` ... just change the capture group to whatever you want it to be, pattern basically stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

In your pattern, in the `.+(.*?)` part, the `(.*?)` captures an empty string as `.+` is greedy and matches the whole line and will only backtrack if you put some obligatory patterns after it. Since there is `\s+` at the end, backtracking only yields the `\n`, but `\r` still remains captured with the `.+` part (remember it is greedy and one `\n` is enough for the `\s+` to match).

Since you multiline string contains a mixture of line ending sequences (CR, LF, CRLF) you might need to account for the `\r` that does not mark a line end and `(?m)^` does not match a location after this CR char, `(?m)^` will only match an empty position after `\n`, LF char.

So, I suggest

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':["basic text\rWHATIWANT: - this is cool ! = . a1^@#%\r\nmore lines"]})
df['col'].str.extract(r'(?m)(?:\r\n?|^)WHATIWANT:\s*(.*\S)\s*$')
# >                             0
# > 0  - this is cool ! = . a1^@#%

df['col'].str.extract(r'(?m)(?:\r\n?|^)(WHATIWANT:.*\S)\s*$')
# >                                         0
# > 0  WHATIWANT: - this is cool ! = . a1^@#%
```

Here,

- `(?m)` - a `re.M` flag inline modifier
- `(?:\r\n?|^)` - CR and an optional LF char, or a position after an LF char or start of string
- `WHATIWANT:` - a string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*\S)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than a line feed char and then any one non-whitespace char
- `\s*$` - zero or more whitespaces and end of line.

When using inline flag modifiers like `(?m)`, you do not have to `import re` explicitly in your script.